# Hash map implementation issue - python

Tags: python, hashmap

I am attempting to implement my own hash map in python but continue to have issues with the insert method.
if self.the_array[hash(item)] is None:
IndexError: list index out of range

```
class My_Hash:

def __init__(self):
    self.size = 10
    self.the_array = self.size*[None]
    self.count = 0

def __len__(self):
    return self.count

def is_empty(self):
    return len(self) == 0

def is_full(self):
    return len(self)>=len(self.the_array)

def hash(self,item):
     value= (ord(item[0]) + ord(item[1]))%self.size
     print (value)
     return value

def resize(self):
    self.size = self.size^2
    new_size = len(self.the_array)^2
    for i in new_size:
        self.the_array.append(None)

def insert(self,item):
   if self.is_full():
       self.resize()
   if self.the_array[hash(item)] is None:  #this is where the error occurs
    self.the_array[hash(item)]= item
    self.count+=1
   else:
       new_hash = hash(item)
       hash_attempt = 0
       while not(self.the_array[new_hash] is None):
           new_hash = ((new_hash + new_hash^2)*3)%len(self.the_array)
           hash_attempt +=1
           if hash_attempt > len(self.the_array)/2:
                self.resize()
       self.the_array[new_hash]= item
```

Comment: Why implement a HashMap? There are Python dictionaries you know that, right?

Comment: should `hash()` be `self.hash()`? Are you calling the class method, instead of the instance method?

Comment: I'm implementing my own for a university project.I think changing it to self.hash() has solved it. Thank you.